# Can't edit a read-only file for which I have the write access and also can not change its permission; how to remount its parent folder?

Tags: linux, file, permissions

I need to edit a file which is read only. This file is located at a remote appliance. Through ssh I logged in to this as admin and I have the root access.

Command "ls -l" show the permissions of file as

```
"-rwxr-xr-x 1 admin root   952 Oct 30 02:01 file.sh"
```

I am not as such familiar with Linux but I searched and found that this above line means that the admin is the owner and he/she has the read and write permission.

But the file is appearing to be read only, I am unable to edit it. So I tried to change the permission using command chomd

```
[admin@appliance targetfolder]# chmod 666 file.sh
chmod: changing permissions of `file.sh': Read-only file system
```

But still it is just read-only.

Someone suggested to remount the folder which contains this file.

How will I remount it, I used

```
" mount -o remount,rw /folde1/folder2/targetFolder"
```

but It gave

```
"mount: can't find /folde1/folder2/targetFolder in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab".
```

Comment: what are the permissions on the directory?.  Also, if you want to make a file as usable by anybody as possible, use `chmod 777 fileName.ext`

Comment: You cannot write to a read-only filesystem. What is the output of `mount`?

Comment: @ mcale For the directory permission is "drwxr-xr-x 3 admin root" so, again being th eadmin I should be able to modify the contents of directory...:/

Comment: @ choroba: how will I remount it, I used " mount -o remount,rw /folde1/folder2/target folder" but I gave "mount: can't find /folde1/folder2/target folder in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab"

Comment: _This file is located at a remote appliance_ - so it must be administered by someone..you need to contact administrator..

Comment: @Rishi Kalia: Yeah, I will but I thought first I should try to resolve it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is solved, I remounted folder by using "mount -o remount,rw /" and then edited the file, without changing any permissions, it worked.